# Substituir uma linha de um ficheiro de bash script

Tags: bash

A situação é a seguinte, tenho 3 variáveis disponíveis:

`numlinha` -> número da linha a substituir

`texto` -> texto da linha que vai ser substituído(preferia usar o número da linha mas isto está aqui caso dê mais jeito)

`texto_sub` -> texto que vai ser substituir

O objetivo é substituir uma linha do ficheiro file.txt, caso dê jeito também posso utilizar outra variável de busca em vez da linha inteira.

Tentei fazer algo do género `sed -i '/$texto/c\$texto_sub' file.txt` mas não funciona no bash script.
A soluçao ideal para mim era substituir com o número da linha mas nada do que tentei e vi funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Use esta opção do sed:

```
sed '17s/string/newstring/' file
```

onde '17' é o número da linha a substituir
Se já quiser trocar diretamente no arquivo, inclua o parâmetro -i

Answer (score 0):

Com o **Sed** vc consegue fazer de boa, mas eu prefiro usar variáveis (**se o texto for curto**), da seguinte forma.

Conteúdo do arquivo.txt

```
cat arquivo.txt
aaa bbb ccc
111 222 333
ddd hhh iii
```

partirei do princípio que as variáveis já estão declaradas.

```
textoantigo="111 222 333"
textonovo="buuuuuuuuuu"
txt_all=$(cat arquivo.txt)
txt_all=${txt_all/$textoantigo/textonovo}
echo "$txt_all" > arquivo.txt
```

como ficou.

```
cat arquivo.txt
aaa bbb ccc
buuuuuuuuuu
ddd hhh iii
```

Lembrando, cuidado com o tamanho do do arquivo pra vc colocar dentro de uma variável.

Answer (score 0):

outro ex:

cat file.txt

teste linha1

teste linha2

teste linha3

awk 'NR==2 {sub($0,  "linha nova")}1' file.txt

teste linha1

linha nova

teste linha3

NR Contém o número do registro atual (numero da linha)

sub  A função "sub" é utilizada para substituir uma string por outra

$0 registro inteiro (pega todo o conteúdo da linha em questao)

"linha nova" novo texto que vai substituir o antigo

1 Para o awk o '1' é visto como true e portanto equivale a imprimir